# How to store binary files in maven nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have setup Maven Nexus repository and configure my project pom to send artifact in to nexus repository.To do that i have used  [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)  my pom look like this.

**pom.xml**

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${xtendGenDirectory}</source>
                                <source>src</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/classes</targetPath>    
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>add-test-resource</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>test-output</directory>
                    <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</targetPath>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution> 

                </executions>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>TASK-7:</scmCommentPrefix>
                    <tagNameFormat>releases/v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The problem was that in nexus **.jar**  artifact it contains copy of my src folder with actual files instead of **.class** files.My requirement is that nexus jar should contains **.class** files instead of actual files.(.java).

I have seen this can be done by execute following command.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache -DartifactId=activemq-distro -Dversion=5.5.1 -Dfile=apache-activemq-5.5.1-bin.tar.gz -DrepositoryId=unapproved-snapshots -Durl=https://xxx
-Dpackaging=tgz
```

But i want to configure pom to do that every build success instead of doing above mentioned way. how can i configure pom files to send binaries into nexus.Do i need add any additional maven plugins to do that?if anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Why are you trying to uplodate apache-activemq cause all those artifacts do exist in [maven central already](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|apache-activemq)?

Comment: @khmarbaise it was just a sample grab from internet.using that command we can send binary files into repository.But my requirement was that configure .pom to send binaries after successful build.

Comment: Best is to integrate those files into your build (either download them from an other source or check in those files with your project) and attach them via build-helper-maven-plugin which you are already using....The jar which contains your source is simply based on the given configuration cause you have configured maven-source-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your quick reply.yes i have configured  maven-source-plugin already.I have ran `mvn clean install` and i can see generated `.jar` file in my target folder.it contains all binary files.Is it possible to configure pom to  send this jar into nexus?if it is how can i configure it.using maven helper plugin?

Comment: If it is producing this jar already than sending to nexus is simply done by `mvn deploy`...

Comment: @khmarbaise but i checked my nexus repository and it contains  jar but inside that jar i cant find any .class files.I need .class files not the actual source files.how can i config pom to set `mvn deploy`.sorry for bothering.i am new to this stuff.

Comment: why it upload src jar instead of jar with `.class` files?Please tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: `.class` files alone will never being uploaded cause they are contained in `.jar` files. Why your build will upload a src jar could only being analysed if having a full working example project (might be created on github)..

Comment: @khmarbaise after project build was successful it created a .jar file in target folder containing .class files in the src.that should be upload to nexus repo.but instead of that it upload jar file but it contains actual src package(as it is) is there any additional config to do in pom?in default it should upload jar with .class files in nexus?